# DELETE FROM + LEFT JOIN SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to delete rows from table using delete.

```
delete a
from "table1" as a
LEFT JOIN "table2" AS b 
on a."x" = b."x" 
where b."X" = 'X'
```

but everything I get is

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected 'a'. syntax error line 3 at position 0 unexpected 'LEFT'.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: can you remove the first "a"?  replace "delete a from" with "delete from" ?

Comment: Why don't you check the documentation? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/delete.html

Answer (score 4):

here is the right syntax in snowflake:

```
delete from "table1" as a
USING "table2" as b 
WHERE a."x" = b."x" 
  and b."X" = 'X'
```

Comment: I am getting "number of rows deleted" 0

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative - using a "merge" query:

```
MERGE INTO "table1" a
USING
(
    SELECT x
    FROM "table2"
    where x = 'X'
) b
ON a.x = b.x
WHEN MATCHED THEN delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `WHERE` and refering to specific value from outer table effectively makes a `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * -- DELETE a
FROM "table1" as a
LEFT JOIN "table2" AS b 
ON a."x" = b."x" 
WHERE b."X" = 'X';
```

---

behaves the same as:

```
SELECT *  -- DELETE a
FROM "table1" as a
INNER JOIN "table2" AS b 
ON a."x" = b."x" 
WHERE b."X" = 'X';
```

---

Depending of requirements it could be rewritten with `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM "table1"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM "table2" 
                 WHERE "table1"."x" = "table2"."x"
                 AND "table2"."x" = 'X');
```